# Minimize the list filter in django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I quite like the filter feature of django admin views (`list_filter`).

But, on views with a lot of fields, I would really like the ability to minimize/expand it with a click, to save screen real-estate and also because it sometimes actually hides stuff.

Is there an easy way to add a collapse button (some already existing plugin I haven't found or something similar)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given that you now have jQuery in django admin, it's easy to bind a `slideToggle()` to the titles in the List Filter.

This seems enough Javascript for it to work:

```
// Fancier version https://gist.github.com/985283 

;(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changelist-filter').children('h3').each(function(){
        var $title = $(this);
        $title.click(function(){
            $title.next().slideToggle();
        });
    });   
  });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Then in the `ModelAdmin` subclass you want to activate that set the Media inner class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_filter = ['bla', 'bleh']
  class Media:
    js = ['js/list_filter_collapse.js']
```

Make sure to drop the list_filter_collapse.js file in a 'js' folder inside your STATIC_DIRS or STATIC_ROOT (Depending on your Django version)

Comment: I'd prefer the whole filter toggles when you click on the part that says "filter"

Comment: Hey this is just what I am looking for, but I have no idea where this javascript code should go. What files should it go in?

Comment: @wobbily_col, the file in Media is relative to STATIC. the way that i did was to create an 'js/admin' directory, and made the file to be loaded 'js/admin/list_filter_collapse.js'.

Comment: @daniyalzade I added the list_filter_collapse.js in my app, js/admin/list_filter_collapse.js as stated, but i always get this error: `"GET /static/js/admin/list_filter_collapse.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1838
`  django 3.2   ```ls -lt static/js/admin/list_filter_collapse.js 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 static/js/admin/list_filter_collapse.js
```

Comment: Is the semicolon at the start necessary? Asking from a backend dev that knows enough javascript to fix bugs.

Answer (score 9):

I changed Jj's answer to collapse the whole filter when clicking on the 'filter' title, adding it here for completeness, a gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/1017597):

```
(function($){
ListFilterCollapsePrototype = {
    bindToggle: function(){
        var that = this;
        this.$filterTitle.click(function(){
            that.$filterContent.slideToggle();
            that.$list.toggleClass('filtered');
        });
    },
    init: function(filterEl) {
        this.$filterTitle = $(filterEl).children('h2');
        this.$filterContent = $(filterEl).children('h3, ul');
        $(this.$filterTitle).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        this.$list = $('#changelist');
        this.bindToggle();
    }
}
function ListFilterCollapse(filterEl) {
    this.init(filterEl);
}
ListFilterCollapse.prototype = ListFilterCollapsePrototype;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changelist-filter').each(function(){
        var collapser = new ListFilterCollapse(this);
    });
});
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: thanks, your js code work better than the others on Django 1.9.9 . Could you make the fiter list be folded by default?

Answer (score 7):

I have written a small snippets downloadable on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/Stanislas/django-foldable-list-filter) for the purpose.

The state of the filters are stored in a cookie and the selected filters stay visible.

[image]

Comment: They are stored in the querystring of the URL for me. Have you done something specific to store them in a cookie?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @JJ's idea.
I added toggles for the whole window, simpler than @abyx's implement.

1. Toggle the whole filter by clicking "Filter" title
2. Toggle each list by clicking list title

---

This is the js file content:

```
;(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changelist-filter > h3').each(function(){
        var $title = $(this);
        $title.click(function(){
            $title.next().slideToggle();
        }); 
    });   
    var toggle_flag = true;
    $('#changelist-filter > h2').click(function () {
        toggle_flag = ! toggle_flag;
        $('#changelist-filter > ul').each(function(){
                $(this).toggle(toggle_flag);
        }); 
    });   
  }); 
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Made another change to this so that the H3's are hidden, as well as the filter lists, when you click on the top H2. This will get the entire list of filters out of the way if you click on the top "Filters".

This is the js file content

```
;(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changelist-filter > h3').each(function(){
        var $title = $(this);
        $title.click(function(){
            $title.next().slideToggle();
        });
    });
    var toggle_flag = true;
    $('#changelist-filter > h2').click(function () {
        toggle_flag = ! toggle_flag;
        $('#changelist-filter').find('> ul, > h3').each(function(){
                $(this).toggle(toggle_flag);
        });
    });
  });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified fanlix solution to:

1. Show cursor as pointer on hover
2. Be folded by default

### Code

```
(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changelist-filter > h3').each(function(){
        var $title = $(this);
        $title.next().toggle();
        $title.css("cursor","pointer");
        $title.click(function(){
            $title.next().slideToggle();
        });
    });
    var toggle_flag = false;
    $('#changelist-filter > h2').css("cursor","pointer");
    $('#changelist-filter > h2').click(function () {
        toggle_flag = ! toggle_flag;
        $('#changelist-filter > ul').each(function(){
            $(this).slideToggle(toggle_flag);
        });
    });
  }); 
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: Will this still work in Django 3.2?

Answer (score 2):

Combined Tim's and maGo's approaches, with some tweaks:

Pros:

- Allows user to hide the entire list (added "click to hide/unhide" to the filter list title so user knows what to do).
- Maintains folded filter categories by default

Cons:

- The page refresh after a filter is selected causes the filter categories to fold once again; ideally the ones you're working with would stay open.

The code:

```
(function($){ $(document).ready(function(){

    // Start with a filter list showing only its h3 subtitles; clicking on any
    // displays that filter's content; clicking again collapses the list:
    $('#changelist-filter > h3').each(function(){
        var $title = $(this);
        $title.next().toggle();
        $title.css("cursor","pointer");
        $title.click(function(){
            $title.next().slideToggle();
        });
    });

    // Add help after title:
    $('#changelist-filter > h2').append("<span style='font-size: 80%; color: grey;'> (click to hide/unhide)</span>");

    // Make title clickable to hide entire filter:
    var toggle_flag = true;
    $('#changelist-filter > h2').click(function () {
        toggle_flag = ! toggle_flag;
        $('#changelist-filter').find('> h3').each(function(){
                $(this).toggle(toggle_flag);
        });
    });
  });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a snippets for menu collapse and single element menu collapse.

It's a fork from abyx code, I've just extended it.

If a filter was previously activated the element menu related to this will start as opened.

The filter menu starts closed as default.
Hope this helps

https://github.com/peppelinux/Django-snippets/tree/master/django-admin.js-snippets

Comment: Please add the code snippet to your answer, do not just link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Giuseppe De Marco's snippet works best. So i am adding his code snippet here for easy access. It even solves the problem (Cons) discussed above by joelg:

```js
// Copied from 
// https://github.com/peppelinux/Django-snippets/tree/master/django-admin.js-snippets

(function($){
    
    var element_2_collapse = '#changelist-filter';
    var element_head       = 'h2'
    var filter_title       = 'h3'
    
    // this is needed for full table resize after filter menu collapse
    var change_list        = '#changelist'
    
    
    ListFilterCollapsePrototype = {
        bindToggle: function(){
            var that = this;
            this.$filterTitle.click(function(){
                
                // check if some ul is collapsed
                // open it before slidetoggle all together
                $(element_2_collapse).children('ul').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(":hidden"))
                        {
                            $(this).slideToggle();
                        }            
                })
                
                // and now slidetoggle all 
                that.$filterContentTitle.slideToggle();
                that.$filterContentElements.slideToggle();            
                that.$list.toggleClass('filtered');
    
            });
    
        },
        init: function(filterEl) {
            this.$filterTitle = $(filterEl).children(element_head);
            this.$filterContentTitle = $(filterEl).children(filter_title);
            this.$filterContentElements = $(filterEl).children('ul');
            $(this.$filterTitle).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            this.$list = $(change_list );
            
            // header collapse
            this.bindToggle();
        
            // collapsable childrens 
            $(element_2_collapse).children(filter_title).each(function(){
                var $title = $(this);
                $title.click(function(){
                    $title.next().slideToggle();
                            
                });
            
            $title.css('border-bottom', '1px solid grey');
            $title.css('padding-bottom', '5px');
            $title.css('cursor', 'pointer');     
            
            });
        
        
            
        }
    }
    function ListFilterCollapse(filterEl) {
        this.init(filterEl);
    }
    ListFilterCollapse.prototype = ListFilterCollapsePrototype;
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(element_2_collapse).each(function(){
            var collapser = new ListFilterCollapse(this);
        });
        
        // close them by default
        $(element_2_collapse+' '+element_head).click()
        
        // if some filter was clicked it will be visible for first run only
        // selezione diverse da Default
        
    
        $(element_2_collapse).children(filter_title).each(function(){
            
            lis = $(this).next().children('li')
            lis.each(function(cnt) {
              if (cnt > 0)
               {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).parent().slideDown(); 
                    $(this).parent().prev().slideDown();
                    
                    // if some filters is active every filters title (h3) 
                    // should be visible
                    $(element_2_collapse).children(filter_title).each(function(){
                        $(this).slideDown(); 
                    })
                    
                    $(change_list).toggleClass('filtered');
                    
                }
               }
            })
    
        });
    
    });
    })(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Django 4.x, here is how I do.

1. create admin template as below

   {% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} {% block extrastyle %}
   {{ block.super }}

   function toggle_filter() {
            $("#changelist-filter").toggle("slow");
        };

        $(document).ready(function(){
            // close them by default
            $("#changelist-filter").toggle("fast");
        });  {% endblock %}
2. enhance admin/base_site.html to add button

```html
<button onclick="toggle_filter()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" type="submit">Toggle Filter</button>
```

Comment: where should the step 1 file be placed by what file name?