# A way to show/hide a field on Django

Tags: python, django

I have this as my list display in Django admin

```
list_display = ('product', 'price', 'purchase_date', 'confirmed', 'get_po_number', 'notes')
```

in models.py:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
     notes = models.TextField( null=True, blank= True)
```

This is what it looks like here:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4fzj.png '

As you can see 'notes' could take up a lot of room, so is there a way I can view/hide that field with the click of a button?

Comment: Alternatively, you can set a specific width to `notes` in `list_display` Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12311286/1628832)

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but is there a simple method for displaying/hiding a field?

Comment: Yeah -  Override the template, and add JQuery to toggle hide of the specific column.

Comment: Overriding the template shouldn't even be necessary. Something along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6086982/630877) should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a button, you can resize the field to become smaller.

```
class PurchaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
formfield_overrides = {
    models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'})},
    models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':40})},
}

admin.site.register(PurchaseOrder, PurchaseAdmin)
```

If you really want to have another button, you can use your custom Inline class to define the fields:

```
class CustomInline(admin.TabularInline):
    readonly_fields = [...'link',...]

    # important part which define what "link" looks like
    def link(self, instance):
       url = # your link to display the note
       return mark_safe(u'<a href="{u}">View Note</a>".format(u=url))
```

And in your custom admin class, use this Inline class instead:

```
class PurchaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CustomInline]
```